# Bandwidth-Pulse Duration Relationship

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

Assuming Gaussian pulse, the relationship between pulse duration and bandwidth is given by:
$$\Delta \nu \cdot \tau \geq 0.441$$
If the rms bandwidth and rms pulse duration are used, then the relationship becomes:
$$\Delta \nu_{rms} \cdot \tau_{rms} \geq 0.5$$
The number 0.5 is exact (according to Lasers - Siegman, p. 334). What are the mathematical steps to go from the first to the second equation?

Comment: First of all, check Lasers - Siegman, p. 333 and 334, eq. 9 through 13 for the complete derivation for Gaussian pulses. The final paragraph on page 334 explains the rest of your question easily as good as I could.

Comment: See also http://onlinedevs.com/bandwidth-pulse-duration-relationship/ - I suspect it's also yours? I think you will find your answer in http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000005776/09_Chapter05.pdf

Comment: @pyramids, you're absolutely correct that the book shows the derivation for the first inequality. However, on the last paragraph of p. 334, he doesn't do a derivation for the second inequality, but instead quote that using rms definition of $\Delta \nu$ and $\tau$ leads to the second equation. That's what my question was about.

Comment: @Floris. Thank you. The chapter you linked was very helpful in that it compares the time-bandwidth relation for different pulse shapes. I still don't know how using rms definitions would lead to the second inequality though

Comment: @HuyNguyen The book refers you to a mathematical truth about the Fourier transform that is the first step in the derivation. If you do not understand why it is true, your question really is about the Fourier transform. If you do not understand the connection, your question is about the English language and I fear a rephrasing would likely be just as incomprehensible.

Comment: Here's an idea: You could sketch a Gaussian distribution and show both the full-width-half-maximum (FWHM) width and the root-mean-square width. These are different. That changes the product of them with the corresponding width of their Fourier transform. If you simply do the math, you get the quoted factors (for 0.44 rounding is involved, as made explicit in eq. 13 of Siegman, p. 334).

Comment: @pyramids This might be a stupid question. But when we say rms, does it mean plus/minus one standard deviation? And FWHM is plus/minus 1.18 stdev? [link](http://www.physi.uni-heidelberg.de/~menzemer/Stat10/statistik_27.04.2010.pdf). IF so, then shouldn't using the rms definition lead to a smaller product? What am I missing here?